# Self Releation in ORMlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I would to make self relation in ORMlite .

I have this structures of chapters in epub .

```
-Chapter 1
---chapter1.1
---chapter1.2
-chapter 2
---chapter2.1
------chapter2.1.1
------chapter2.1.2
-chapter3
```

and so on .

i would to save the same relationships between chapters (parent and child).

In chapter dto i already done the self relation as blow

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ChapterDto
{

//all of my attributes 

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    private ChapterDto parent;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerLevel = 99)
    Collection<ChapterDto> subChapters;

}
```

my question , how to insert data correctly with this relation ? 
Thanks in advance .